# Склонение фамилии

Tags: морфология, склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли фамилии "Капуш" и "Капуша" - мужской, женский род

Answer (score 1):

Это две фамилии?
Если да, то первая (Калуш) - изментяется по падежам только как мужская, вторая (Калуша) - в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0):

В мужском роде - да, склоняется по падежам. В женском - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, Грамота.ру, измученная вопросами о склонении фамилий, написала очень проникновенную статью с подробным алгоритмом: http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Статья на грамоте довольно древняя...
Для полноты картины моя на неё реакция.
 
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4091  

Некоторые вещи обещали использовать (и якобы даже внесли испраления, но потом почему-то произошел откат на исходную версию без моих дополнений. 
Я не в обиде, но упомянуть об этой ситуации имею право.)))

Comment: Почитала ваши замечания по ссылке, в очередной раз порадовалась, как хорошо иметь простую фамилию типа Иванов:)

Comment: ага, или Соколов. Зато по сложной фамилии тебя любой дурак легко найдёт в интернетах.

Comment: Это хорошо или плохо?

Comment: Когда я ищу информацию, хорошо. Когда обо мне ищут - нейтрально. Таким образом, общий итог - положительный.